# how to get the data after a particlaur string

Tags: php, string

I have a string like this:

```
Time In: 8:15 AM Time Out: 12:30 PM Comments: Time In: 1:00 PM Time Out: 4:45 PM Comments:
```

My goal is to get times from above string including AM/PM. 
 
I tried in this  way:

```php
$commentData ='Time In: 8:15 AM Time Out: 12:30 PM Comments: Time In: 1:00 PM Time Out: 4:45 PM Comments:'

preg_match_all("/In: ([^\s]+)/", $commentData, $inMatches);
preg_match_all("/Out: ([^\s]+)/", $commentData, $outMatches); 
$inMatches[1][0];
echo $inMatches[1][1];
echo $$outMatches[1][0];
echo $outMatches[1][1];
```

I am getting the values like:

8:15
1:00
12:30
4:45

But I want with AM and PM also .

Comment: Can you add the language in your tags to be clearer?

Comment: add AM/PM in your regex exp

Answer (score 1):

You can update your preg_match_all with *(AM|PM)*:

```
preg_match_all("/In: ([^\s]+) (AM|PM)/", $commentData, $inMatches);
preg_match_all("/Out: ([^\s]+) (AM|PM)/", $commentData, $outMatches); 

echo $inMatches[1][0]." ".$inMatches[2][0];
echo $inMatches[1][1]." ".$inMatches[2][1];
echo $outMatches[1][0]." ".$outMatches[2][0];
echo $outMatches[1][1]." ".$outMatches[2][1];
```

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```html
echo date('h:i A', strtotime("8:15"));
 echo date('h:i A', strtotime("1:00"));
 echo date('h:i A', strtotime("12:30"));
 echo date('h:i A', strtotime("4:45"));
```

Comment: that's not quite related. OP wants to grab from the string instead.